# Cockroach Db with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, cockroachdb

While using Coacroach Db with Spring Boot and Spring Batch, I am getting the following error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Europe/London"
```

Detail: The system cannot find the path specified.

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=disable&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone= UTC

spring.batch.initialize-schema = always
```

I also added this and above properties as mentioned somewhere but didn't help.

```
@PostConstruct
void started() {
  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, which operating system are you using? We have an [open issue relating to timezones](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/36864), which is known to affect Windows.

When you specify the UTC timezone, do you receive the same error as you do with "Europe/London"? What if you try using a numerical offset, like "+0:00"?

Also, when setting the timezone through the URL, the parameter should be `timezone=utc` (or whichever other value you want).

Comment: yes, I am using the windows machine. How to set it via URL?

Comment: Try using this URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=disable&timezone=UTC

Answer (score 0):

So see a number of issues.

```
1.  You said you are using Coacroach Db but you seem to be loading a JDBC JAR and ULR string for Postgres.  

2.  Posgres does not have "Europe/London" as a valid TimeZone String.  There is a "Europe/London GB GB-Eire" 
See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/datetime-keywords.html

3.  You have a space in the time zone property name.
    This:       spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone= UTC
    Should Be:  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

Comment: 1) what should the correct URL? 2) I haven't set timezone Europe/London, not sure of where it is coming. 3 ) space didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Well the database URL whould be something only you would know, but if it is a CoacroachDB as you said then the URL should not have Posgres in it.   "jdbc:postgresql://localhost" and should not be using the Postgres drivers "org.postgresql.Driver"

Comment: there is no driver for cockroach db

Comment: There is no JDBC driver at all?   Then you could never use it in Java, so I doubt that is the case.   Either way knowing using the wrong one will not work well.

Comment: @BrianC CockroachDB is wire-compatible with Postgres. @ChandreshMishra is correct to use the PGJDBC driver and a URL with the `postgresql` prefix.

We have a tutorial here to get started with CockroachDB and Spring Boot. (disclaimer: I work on CockroachDB.) https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/tutorial-spring-hibernate/